# Why is energy produced from uranium not exactly mass times velocity squared?

Tags: energy, mass-energy, radioactivity

Our technology teacher explained why $1 \;\text{kg}$ of enriched uranium does not produce
$$E=(1 \;\text{kg})*c^2$$
[where $c$ is the speed of light], but I didn't get it, so why is this so? (Nuclear fission).

Comment: velocity? or  speed of light?  Energy produced via what processes?

Comment: Reaction equation?

Comment: seems Vincent Thacker amended my edit, that's it

Answer (score 1):

The Energy produced is, $$E=\Delta M c^2$$ where $\Delta M$ is the change in mass.

Uranium or for that matter, any fissile element doesn't use up whole of its mass in decaying, more plainly, uranium decays to something else which has mass. You can't have 1 Kg of Uranium that decays and vanishes of the surface. There are certain things/particles that have to be conserved.

Say, Uranium Decays to Radium, so $\Delta M$ here is the difference in mass of these two materials.

Comment: the "things" are "quantum numbers"

Comment: Thanks for the comment!